# ASP.NET if route parameter is not given then do something

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've got some routing with parameters set-up in ASP.NET MVC 4 + Razor.

I am passing a parameter of {id} to the controller... and then on the controller I want to check the following:

**A.** if the id exists in the database, return view

**B.** if the id was not provided, redirect to Index

I've no idea how to go about doing those - and searching around doesn't really provide any information.

Could someone show me how to do an if / else statement to check if {id} has been provided?

The controller:

```
public ActionResult View(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your method parameter a **[nullable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) int** so that it will work for the request urls such as

`yourDomainName/yourController/view` and `yourDomainName/yourController/view/25`

```
public ActionResult View(int? id)
{
   if(id!=null)  // id came in the request
   {
      int postId= id.Value;
      var postViewModel = new PostViewModel { Id=postId};

      // Use postId to get your entity/View model from db and then return view
      // The below is the code to get data from Db. 
      // Read further if your data access method is different.

      var db = new MyDbContext()

      var post=db.Posts.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id==postId);
      if(post!=null)
      {
          postViewModel.Title = post.Title;
          return View(postViewModel);
      }
      return View("PostNotFound"); // Make sure you have this view.
   }
   //If code reaches here, that means no id value came in request.
   return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Assuming `MyDbContext` is your DbContext class and you are using Entity framework for data access. If your data access method is different ( ADO.NET/NHibernate etc..), You may update that part of code with your data access code.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you so much! Your code helped me add error handling to this too. :)